# Any tutorial available for add SDL library to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sdl

I have searched quite expansively for a tutorial explaining how to add an SDL lib to Visual Studio 2012 but have found nothing. I was wondering if anybody knew of a good tutorial that will explain how this can be done.

So far I have found out how to link the library and add the include and lib paths but when I execute my test program I get an error saying that the application was unable to start correctly. The program builds with no errors but produces an error when running.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <SDL.h>
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
        {
           return -1;
        }

        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

But if you get it compiling correctly there might be another error. Check if all *.dll s are on the right place

Actually, you can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check if all dlls can be found. This does not detect dynamically loaded dlls though (see [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/application_profiling.htm) for a guide to detect them, too).